# missing bcrypt in github actions windows 2019

Tags: windows, cmake, github-actions, visual-studio-2019, bcrypt

I am trying to compile https://github.com/ValveSoftware/GameNetworkingSockets in my project.
I want to use bcrypt on windows specifically to avoid to need to install openssl.

I am running tests using github actions with both windows-2019 and windows-2022.
Unfortunately, windows-2019 seems to be missing bcrypt.
(Windows-2022 works fine.)

```
-- Looking for BCryptEncrypt
-- Looking for BCryptEncrypt - not found
CMake Error at externals/gamenetworkingsockets/GameNetworkingSockets/CMakeLists.txt:95 (message):
  You're on Windows but BCrypt seems to be unavailable, you will need OpenSSL
```

How can it be missing? Bcrypt is supposed to be available since windows vista.

Thanks for any hints.

Edit (in reaction to Chuck Walbourn):
I have tried this change in cmake

```
if(WIN32)
    cmake_push_check_state()
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES bcrypt)
    check_symbol_exists(BCryptEncrypt windows.h BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_WINDOWS)
    check_symbol_exists(BCryptEncrypt bcrypt.h BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BCRYPT)
    check_symbol_exists(BCryptEncrypt "windows.h;bcrypt.h" BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_WB)
    check_symbol_exists(BCryptEncrypt "bcrypt.h;windows.h" BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_BW)
    message(STATUS "BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_WINDOWS: ${BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_WINDOWS}")
    message(STATUS "BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BCRYPT: ${BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BCRYPT}")
    message(STATUS "BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_WB: ${BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_WB}")
    message(STATUS "BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_BW: ${BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_BW}")
    cmake_pop_check_state()
endif()
```

and none of these would work on windows-2019.

```
windows-2019:
-- BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_WINDOWS: 
-- BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BCRYPT: 
-- BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_WB: 
-- BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_BW:
```

It seems to require windows.h when run on windows-2022.

```
windows-2022:
-- BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_WINDOWS: 1
-- BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BCRYPT: 
-- BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_WB: 1
-- BCRYPT_AVAILABLE_IN_BOTH_BW:
```

Interestingly, it generates syntax error in bcrypt.h itself when included before windows.h:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\bcrypt.h(39,31): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'return' [F:\personal\cage-examples\externals\cage\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_61959.vcxproj]
```

You can see the whole experiment here: https://github.com/ucpu/cage/actions/runs/5527056766/jobs/10082429219

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the upstream CMakeLIsts.txt isn't really robust:

```
    cmake_push_check_state()
        set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES bcrypt)
        check_symbol_exists(BCryptEncrypt windows.h BCRYPT_AVAILABLE)
    cmake_pop_check_state()
```

That symbol has *never* been in Windows.h, although I'm guessing it just works through the fact that `Windows.h` is incredibly bloated.

A better version of that line would be `check_symbol_exists(BCryptEncrypt bcrypt.h BCRYPT_AVAILABLE)`